# Integral in Stata when upper limit is infinity

Tags: stata, integral

How can we calculate the integral of the integrand with the lower limit 0 and upper limit infinity in Stata? I am aware of the `integ` command, but I am not sure whether I can use that when the upper limit is infinity.

Comment: 1) This question really belongs on a different site, since it's about a particular language and has not, on appearances, got anything to do with statistics at all.  2) Have you tried using the `integ` command to see if it will work?  Perhaps with a really large upper limit if infinity isn't an option?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about numerical integration in STATA, not statistics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `integrate` from SSC to do numerical integration for one dimensional functions like this:

```
. integrate, f(normalden(x)) l(.) u(.)

    Note: The function to be integrated will be compiled using Mata and stored in your personal directory ~/ado/personal/ (make sure this is writeable)

The integral = 1
```